# Deleting question

Tags: support

What happens to my reputation when I delete a question from me?

I ask this because there are some issues that could be better prepared. Or is it better to edit them and improve them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you delete them, any reputation (upvotes/downvotes) accrued from them is removed. Whether to remove your questions or just edit them is entirely your call if there are no answers; if there are already upvoted answers, however, the system will not let you delete those questions.

Comment: There are some time restrictions to losing the rep from deletion. You don't lose rep if your post is > 60 days old and has a score of 3+.